# Can Date API/Calendar and CCK send an argument to Views with data from a field?

Tags: views, 6, nodes, datetime

I have a data/calendar content type using the Date API and Calendar Modules. Each event I add to the calendar uses Advanced Node Reference and returns a list of 5 other events of the same type.

What I want is a list of the next five events following the event node's *advertised* event date (not the date it was published). If a new event node is added, and it falls within the *next five events* parameter, then when the page is generated, it is listed, bumping the furthest future event from the list. If a event node is removed, then a new (previously out of range) event node is added to the list. It is a simple sort, and very reasonable requirement using the "advertised" date and not the "published" date. The field data would be the advertised date.

The Node Reference module allows a view to be used to make the selection to populate the node reference. This I have also done. The problem is the list of possible dates/events to be linked are produced by a filter with *relative* date value from *today's* date ('>= now'), rather than from the node's content value for *event date*.

*TDW* might use an argument to pass the current date value of the date/event being edited to Views. If this exists, where is it? What is it? Some kind of [keyword] to pass in the allowed argument field of the Advanced Node Reference of this Date Content Type?

If this was a PHP template I was hand coding, the value of the current form's 'event date' field would be available from the query used to populate the form. In Drupal I don't know where this is. I'm still a newbie at Devel Module and its variables page was no help.

Comment: please tag your issue with the drupal version.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you need to do a relationship to the parent node, and then use a Filter by node published date using that relationship.

Comment: After reading your answer, I realized the question needed to be edited. The trouble with the publish date is the event may be written, published at any interval. Yet the event's date will by necessity remain constant. A programmatic solution is preferable to enforcing a protocol for publishing the event (-;